# Sorting through call recordings from Amazon Connect

Tags: lambda, salesforce, amazon-connect

I have a connection from my Amazon Connect instance to Salesforce, which uses AC as the dialer. I also now required to connect Gong to Amazon Connect, in order to process the recordings located in the S3 bucket that AC generates. However my issue is to only be sending through calls that are related to Sales - either by sorting them through agent, queue or call flows. AC connects to a single bucket and file hierarchy where it stores the recordings, and Gong can only connect to a single bucket, and because of Salesforce, only one instance of AC can be used. How can I either send recordings to different buckets at the time of creation, or sort through recordings after they are published to the bucket, to only be sending specific ones to a separate bucket? If you also have any suggestion, or other solutions on how to be working through this, I am all ears.

Explored have 2 instances - cannot do that due to the Salesforce limitation.
Looked at querying in the s3 bucket to sort through the recordings, but not enough information is telling them apart to use it in a query.